# I got Bad State flutter : to many element issue, how to solving this because i stuck about this?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have condition if i'm gonna to click button and will showing issue bad state, i don't know about issue's about bad state, i found it at other issue's then i read this issue's about same key i don't know about this, it's a my function to checkout order, then in the UI i using this function, please check it below :

> function.dart

```
 Future<void> getCheckoutOrder(
      {String voucherId = '', int addressId = -1, bool? fromFoucher}) async {
    print('get voucher id : $voucherId');
    selectedVoucherId = voucherId;
    isLoading.value = true;
    MainController mainController = Get.find<MainController>();
    var response = await BaseClient()
        .getWithHeaders(
      baseUrl: ApiServices.baseUrlDev,
      api: ApiServices.apiGetCheckoutItem +
          (voucherId.isNotEmpty ? '?voucherId=$voucherId&' : '') +
          (addressId != -1
              ? '?addressId=$addressId'
              : '?lat=${mainController.selectedAddress.value.latitude}&long=${mainController.selectedAddress.value.longitude}'),
      emailHeader: authenticationController.userFB.value!.email!,
    )
        .catchError((e) async {
      print('err at ${ApiServices.apiGetCheckoutItem}');
      print('errornya apa  => ${e.message}');
      if (jsonDecode(e.message)['message'] ==
              "Destination is out of delivery range" ||
          jsonDecode(e.message)['message'] ==
              "Failed to calculate destination distance") {
        print('masuk sini !');
        Get.dialog(Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: Get.width * 0.4, horizontal: Get.width * 0.05),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32))),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Image.asset('assets/images/unknown.png'),
              Text(
                'Your location is too far',
                style: AppStyles.blackTextStyle1.copyWith(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Container(
                width: Get.width * 0.7,
                child: Text(
                  'Sorry your destination address is currently outside Troline coverage area. Please make sure the distance does not exceed 16 km.',
                  softWrap: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: Get.width * 0.8,
                height: Get.height * 0.07,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // Get.back();
                      mainController.isFromLocationTooFar.value = true;
                      Get.back();
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.CHANGESUSERADDRESS);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 0,
                        primary: ColorConstants.cyan1,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        )),
                    child: Text(
                      'Find Other Location',
                      style: AppStyles.blackTextStyle1,
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
      } else if (([500, 502].contains(jsonDecode(e.message)['code']) ||
              jsonDecode(e.message)['message'].toString().toLowerCase() ==
                  'internal server error') &&
          _checkoutOrderErrorRetry < 3) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () async {
          toastNotification('retrying');
          _checkoutOrderErrorRetry++;
          print('retrying');
          await getCheckoutOrder(
              voucherId: voucherId,
              addressId: addressId,
              fromFoucher: fromFoucher);
        });
      } else {
        handleError(e);
      }
    });
    isLoading.value = false;

    print('response ${ApiServices.apiGetCheckoutItem} => $response');
    try {
      checkout.value = checkoutModelFromJson(response);
      if (fromFoucher ?? false) {
        if (checkout.value.voucher.isVoucherApplied) {
        } else {
          throw 'Promo is not applicable';
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _checkoutOrderErrorRetry = 0;

      print('err checkout value : $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

> ui.dart

```
ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              // var userValue = Get.find<AuthenticationController>().userFB.value;
                              if (authController.userFB.value != null) {
                                try {
                                  Get.find<MainController>()
                                      .isFromLocationTooFar
                                      .value = false;
                                  DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>
                                      userLoginData = await FirebaseFirestore
                                          .instance
                                          .collection('users')
                                          .doc(authController.userFB.value!.uid)
                                          .get();
                                  print(
                                      'phoneNumber => ${userLoginData.data()!['phoneNumber']}');
                                  if (userLoginData.data()!['phoneNumber'] !=
                                          null &&
                                      userLoginData.data()!['phoneNumber'] !=
                                          '') {
                                    await checkoutContoroller
                                        .getCheckoutOrder();
                                    // }

                                    checkoutContoroller
                                        .getSelectedScheduledBatch();
                                    // handle when user click the check out button and navigate to the checkout screen [preventDuplicates:false]
                                    checkoutContoroller.resetCheckoutOptions();
                                    Get.toNamed(Routes.CHECKOUT,
                                        preventDuplicates: false);
                                  } else {
                                    Get.snackbar(
                                      " Phone number not found.",
                                      'Please go to your profile and add your phone number.',
                                      icon: Image.asset(
                                          'assets/images/troline_logo_whitebg.png',
                                          width: 30,
                                          height: 30),
                                      snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                                      backgroundColor: ColorConstants.white,
                                      borderRadius: 20,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                      colorText: ColorConstants.black,
                                      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                                      isDismissible: true,
                                      dismissDirection:
                                          DismissDirection.horizontal,
                                      forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOutBack,
                                    );                                      
                                  }
                                } catch (e, sss) {
                                  print(sss);
                                  print('err checkout : $e');
                                }
                              } else {
                                Get.back();
                                Get.toNamed(Routes.SIGNINSIGNUP);
                              }
                            },
```

Comment: what line that the error appear?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show detailed error messages if you have them.